# how to have check box value unchecked set to blank

Tags: xpages

I have an check box control on an xapge bound to a field on a document. The value unchecked gets set to false. I would like it to be blank. How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `uncheckedValue` property of the check box setting it to blank value. Below is the sample code snippet.

`<xp:checkBox text="Label" id="checkBox1" value="#{document1.Checkbox}" uncheckedValue=""></xp:checkBox>`

This would save the blank value in the document. *One caveat, via Domino Designer you cannot set this property to blank as it removes the property so you have to do this in source.*